# MobX observable boolean does not re-render component, but observable number does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I'm getting started with a new `create-react-app` application using TypeScript, hooks, and `mobx-react-lite`. Despite having used MobX extensively in a React Native app in the past, I've run into an issue that doesn't make any sense to me.

I have a store with two observables: one number and one boolean. There is an `initialize()` method that runs some library code, and in the success callback, it sets the number and the boolean to different values (see Line A and Line B below).

The issue: my component ONLY re-renders itself when Line A is present. In that case, after the initialization is complete, the 'ready' text appears, and the button appears. If I delete Line B, the 'ready' text still appears. But if I delete Line A (and keep Line B), *the button never renders*. I've checked things over a hundred times, everything is imported correctly, I have decorator support turned on. I can't imagine why observing a number can trigger a re-render but observing a boolean cannot. I'm afraid I'm missing something horribly obvious here. Any ideas?

The relevant, simplified code is as follows:

```js
// store/app.store.ts
export class AppStore {
  @observable ready = false
  @observable x = 5

  initialize() {
    // Takes a callback
    ThirdPartyService.init(() => {
      this.ready = true
      this.x = 10
    })
  }
}
```

```js
// context/stores.ts

const appStore = new AppStore()
const storesContext = React.createContext({
  appStore
})

export const useStores = () => React.useContext(storesContext)
```

```
// App.tsx
const App = observer(() => {
  const { appStore } = useStores()

  useEffect(() => {
    appStore.initialize()
  }, [appStore])

  return (
    <div>
      { appStore.x === 10 && 'ready' } // <-- Line A
      { appStore.ready && <button>Go</button> } // <-- Line B
    </div>
  )
}
```

**EDIT:** A bit more information. I've added some logging statements to just before the `return` statement for the `App` component. I also refactored the `button` conditional to a `const`. This may provide more insight:

```js
const button = appStore.ready ? <button>Go</button> : null
console.log('render', appStore.ready)
console.log('button', button)

return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">{button}</header>
  </div>
)
```

When `appStore.ready` is updated, the component *does* re-render, but the DOM isn't updated. The console shows `'render' true` and shows a representation of the button, as it should, but inspecting the document itself shows no button there. Somehow, though, changing the condition from `appStore.ready` to `appStore.x === 10` *does* update the DOM.

Comment: The code looks perfectly normal indeed. Can you create a minimal reproduction (e.g. as a standalone project on github)?

Comment: actually... I don't see the `@action` decorator on `initialize()` - is it just omited from the sample code or it's actually missing in the real app?

Comment: @amakhrov It's missing from the app but I've tried decorating `initialize()` with `@action`, `@action.bound`, and I've tried running the updates to `ready` and `x` within `runInAction()`, but unfortunately none have made a difference. I will get a reproduction together and link it here soon, thanks. I've also updated my question with more information in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't quite give complete information in my question. While I was creating a minimal reproduction, I decided to try dropping the top-level `<React.StrictMode>` component from `index.tsx`. Suddenly, everything worked. As it happens, `mobx-react-lite@1.5.2`, the most up-to-date stable release at the time of my project's creation, does not play nice with Strict Mode. Until it's added to a stable release, the two options are:

- Remove strict mode from the React component tree
- Use `mobx-react-lite@next`